# Raspberry pi ok as usb drive

Tags: pi-2

I want to make a raspberry pi model B , into a usb drive. I know that there are many tutorials available over the internet, but I want to make a change in it , which I can't find anywhere.

Goal:
The raspberry pi will have a micro sd card with raspbian loaded and a male usb port(to connect to a computer). 
The modification: I wanted to store the Vnc and the putty software on thw micro sd card, so that when I connect the pi  to a computer,  it detects the pi as a usb drive and would show the 2 software's. (So in this way I wont have to carry the software seperately) Then using vnc i connect to the pi and use it.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: which of the tutorials are you changing? .... please update your question

Answer (score 1):

You can't - the USB ports are connected via a hub. It may be possible with a Pi Zero or A.